# bacula vmware как бакапить

Tags: ubuntu, vmware

доброго дня, подскажите пожалуйста есть ли статья какая может, как с помощью bacula
бакапить vmware виртуальный сервер без выключения? 
Я не смог найти ничего более менее рабочего